# javax.validation.ValidationException: Type interface org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodValidator not supported

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

am using spring 3.1 and hibernate validator 4.2. we have custom traversal resolver and registered as Spring bean after that we have create vlaidaton factory using below code

```
<bean id="validatorFactory"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" >
<property name="traversableResolver" ref="traversableResolver"/>
    <property name="validationPropertyMap">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="hibernate.validator.fail_fast" value="false" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="traversableResolver"
    class="org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver" >
    <constructor-arg ref="delegate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="methodValidatorAdvice" class="common.validator.MethodValidationAspect">
    <constructor-arg ref="validatorFactory"/>
</bean>
```

when spring try to initialize the MethodValidatonAspect which is implment with MethodValidationInterceptor, we got below expceiton
javax.validation.ValidationException: Type interface org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodValidator not supported

added log entry
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Type interface org.hibernate.validator.method.MethodValidator not supported

```
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.unwrap(ValidatorImpl.java:263)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.<init>(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:82)
at com.cisco.sdp.core.common.validator.MethodValidationAspect.<init>(MethodValidationAspect.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at com.cisco.sdp.spring.core.SDPClassPathApplicationContext.<init>(SDPClassPathApplicationContext.java:52)
at com.cisco.sdp.spring.core.SDPClassPathApplicationContext.<init>(SDPClassPathApplicationContext.java:63)
at com.cisco.sdp.spring.core.SDPClassPathApplicationContext.<init>(SDPClassPathApplicationContext.java:57)
at com.cisco.sdp.spring.core.SDPClassPathApplicationContext.<init>(SDPClassPathApplicationContext.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:528)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:374)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:243)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1838)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
```

Comment: we were deploying the above application into weblogic server

Comment: format your code properly

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, I fixed it when I put jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar into my class path. I don't know why.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
 </dependency>
```

If the problem was still annoying you, try these dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```